# Does Cloud Load Balancer support QUIC when connecting to an upstream server?

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer, quic

[Introducing QUIC support for HTTPS load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-quic-support-https-load-balancing) explains how QUIC is supported for a client <-> load balancer connection. My upstream server uses [aioquic](https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic) and accepts only HTTP/3 connections attempted proactively, without support for upgrading from HTTP/1.1 or HTTP2. Can I configure Cloud Load Balancer to always communicate with my upstream servers in Google Kubernetes Engine via HTTP/3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you cannot use QUIC/HTTP3 backend, when using the HTTP(S) loadbalancing the following backend protocols are supported:

`HTTP, HTTPS, HTTP/2`

Please see this for more [info](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#protocol_to_the_backends) on backend protocols supported.